# How to fetch data from mongodb and show using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Following is my code to fetch data from a collection and show it on index page, but it is not giving the results.

**Node Code**-

```
var app = require('express')();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/test';

mongoose.connect(dbURI);
var testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        rollnum: String
});

var Test = mongoose.model('Test', testSchema);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
        Test.find({},function(err, docs){
                res.send('index',{docs:docs});
        });
        //res.send('test');
});

app.listen(3001);
```

However I check and have a collection in db like this -

Query fire - `db.testinfo.find()`

Output -

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("123456..78"),
"name": "test",
"rollnum": "XXXX"
}
```

After hitting the URL - `http://127.0.0.1:3001/`

This is the output I am getting -

```
{
  "docs": []
}
```

However I was expecting to get the result of name, rollnum.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you register a model in Mongoose, it uses the pluralized, lower-cased model name as the name of the collection it's tied to.  So because your model name is `Test`, the collection name is `tests`.

To tie the model to `testinfo` instead, pass that name as the third parameter to your `model` call:

```
var Test = mongoose.model('Test', testSchema, 'testinfo');
```

Comment: wow that works..sorry for the late response..was taking the meal :)

Comment: just for my knowledge..can you please refer any good link or book to follow for node+mongoose where I can easily understand the CRUD concepts for node+mongo beginner as I searched over the internet and everone is following thr own conventions so I am lost being a beginner